# Checksum of file in vbscript

Tags: command-line, vbscript, fciv

I have the following command
`"C:\Program Files\File Checksum Integrity Verifier\fciv.exe" -sha1 "D:\new.txt"`

How to run this command from vbscript? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

VBScript comes with a couple of different ways to execute command lines, both of which are on the WshShell object ([WScript.Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99%28v=vs.84%29.aspx))

Using [WshShell.Exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

```
Dim WshShell, oExec
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("""C:\Program Files\File Checksum Integrity Verifier\fciv.exe"" -sha1 ""D:\new.txt""")

Do While oExec.Status = 0
     WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

WScript.Echo oExec.Status
```

Using [WshShell.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files\File Checksum Integrity Verifier\fciv.exe"" -sha1 ""D:\new.txt""", 1, true
```

Comment: How to store the result in a variable generated by fciv?